# SharePoint classic team site -> Office 365 Group in Azure Functions

Tags: sharepoint, office365, azure-functions

I'm trying to link a classic site to a office 365 group in a Azure function. But I'm having problem to connect to Connect-SPOService. Do I use this correct?

```
$adminUrl = "https://" +$keyResponseAppTenant +"-admin.sharepoint.com"
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl -Credential $cred
Set-SPOSiteOffice365Group -Site $url -DisplayName $title -Alias $title -IsPublic:$false
```

Error in function:
[image]

Then I probably have to add the "module"? Do I take the whole folder from "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to upload "sharepoint online management shell"-files from that folder :D